# высвечивает красным,работает

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Почему так происходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения],обьясните...
Писал все в file.jsp  java code

Comment: Глюк IDE, закройте - откройте, может пройдет

Comment: не помогает даже комп перезапускал

Comment: Не знаю, уберите статический импорт System.* , может там что то не так.